# java - Метод `sqrt`.

Tags: java

Есть класс `Math`. У него есть метод `sqrt`. На вход ему подавай `double`, он из этого числа возьмёт корень и возвращает результат. **Как?** Ведь никакой такой формулы не существует! (или моя учительница по математике ошибается?) Как этот метод работает?

Comment: `sqrt(a)` – это решение уравнения `x^2=a`, следовательно, чтобы вычислить `sqrt(a)`, нужно решить (в общем случае) трансцендентное уравнение. Далее можете посмотреть как численно решаются уравнения. Вариант два: использовать разложение корня в ряд.

Comment: Если x = sqrt(y), то y = x^2, и дальше все уходит в тривиальное квадратное уравнение с одним корнем (потому что второй окажется отрицательным). Вряд ли ваша учительница не знала квадратных уравнений. Кроме того, есть [куча специализированных методов](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Methods_of_computing_square_roots), включая забавную адаптацию метода Ньютона, которая с каждой итерацией уточняет значение, пока не добьется заданной точности.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Для любой функции, бесконечно дифференцируемой в некоторой точке а, существует разложение в ряд Тейлора в этой точке, этот ряд содержит бесконечное число членов, но для вычисления значения с некоторой точностью можно взять некоторое конечное число членов.
Благодаря этому можно много чего вычислять, в том числе, например, находить численно "неберущиеся" интегралы.

Ссылка по теме: [Ряд Тейлора](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A0%D1%8F%D0%B4_%D0%A2%D0%B5%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0)

Answer (score 0):

> Ведь никакой такой формулы не существует!

А как же народ корни извлекает? по наитию, что ли? Квадратный корень вообще можно даже в столбик извлекать - ненамного сложнее деления...

> Как этот метод работает?

Есть у процессора команда FSQRT, например...